# Usort multidimensional array in PHP isn't working for me

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, usort

Using the example straight from the docs, I can't see to figure out why I am getting the results I am.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["fruit"], $b["fruit"]);
}

$fruits[0]["fruit"] = 1000;
$fruits[1]["fruit"] = 600;
$fruits[2]["fruit"] = 2180;

echo ("<pre>");
echo " before  \n";
print_r($fruits);
echo ("</pre>");

usort($fruits, "cmp");

echo ("<pre>");
echo "  after \n";
print_r($fruits);
echo ("</pre>");
```

These are the results:

```
 before  
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => 1000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => 600
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => 2180
        )

)
  after 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => 1000
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [fruit] => 2180
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [fruit] => 600
    )
```

)

I thought usort was meant to organise based on a value within a multidimensional array. Sometimes it sorts it, sometimes it just gives a random order as the output array. Am I missing something? Also, this is defo not a duplicate question, read it carefully there is nothing like it on this site.

Comment: _Am I missing something?_ Yes, integers are not strings so don't use a string comparison function.

Comment: Always assume that you are in the wrong initially. It is not PHP's usort function that is broken; it is the user's logic in this case. Learn to properly identify the types and operations you are working with. You are comparing the numbers as strings and PHP is sorting those strings appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are using the function [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strcmp.php) to compare the **integers**, but this function is made to compare *binary safe strings*. You need to use another function or just an operator like `>`. So, your array has been sorted correctly by PHP.